# Add page number with offset to docx using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I'm using Apache POI to generate docx document. With the following code I could add automatically generated number to the footer:

```
private void createDocFooter(XWPFDocument docx) {

    XWPFFooter footer = docx.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);

    XWPFParagraph paragraph = footer.getParagraphArray(0);
    if (paragraph == null) {
        paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
    }

    paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

    paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("PAGE");
}
```

Problem is that it always starts from 1. How could provide offset to that instruction to start numbering from e.g. 5?

Comment: this code helped me immensely. thank you my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page number start value is set in section properties. If there is only one section, then this are the section properties of the document body.

Apache POI does not provide any methods to set section properties in it's hig level classes. So one would need using the underlying low level classes of `ooxml`.

Following method should do what you had asked for. It sets start of page numbering type to page given in `start`.

```
 private void setPageNumberStart(XWPFDocument doc, java.math.BigInteger start) {
  if(doc.getDocument().getBody().isSetSectPr()) {
   if (doc.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().isSetPgNumType()) {
    doc.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgNumType().setStart(start);
   } else {
    doc.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().addNewPgNumType().setStart(start);
   }
  } else {
   doc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr().addNewPgNumType().setStart(start);
  }  
 }
```

When called like:

```
...
XWPFDocument doc = ...
...
setPageNumberStart(doc, java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(5));
...
```

it sets start of page numbering type to page 5.